# How to split a string with two reserved characters

Tags: java, android, arrays

How can I split the brackets and curly braces?

```
String items = [{person1=John Smith, person2=William Anderson}]
```

I have tried this code `String start = items.split("\\[\\{")[0];` But this won't work.

I want to remove the brackets and curly braces, so my output should just look like this, `person1=John Smith, person2=William Anderson`

Comment: Give an example of the output you want, because it is not clear from your question.

Comment: what do you mean by _" split the brackets and curly braces"_? what is your expected result?

Comment: what value you want as output??? please be specific..

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question. @DavidChoweller

Comment: Another thing: your line doesn't even compile.  Is this some sort of Android-specific `String` declaration?

Comment: you need `#String.replaceAll()` instead of `#String.split()`

Comment: Like this: `items.replaceAll("[]{}\\[]", "")`

Comment: Have you tried ` String start = items.split("\\[\\{")[1]` ?

Comment: `split` is the wrong tool for this job.  `split` is for when you have a string with multiple items, separated by a delimiter, and you want to split the string into an array of those items.  That isn't what you want to do here.

Comment: `String [] arr = items.split("[\\[\\]\\{\\}]+");` will give you what you want in `arr[1]` assuming you want to use `split` instead of `replaceAll`

Comment: @DavidChoweller You don't need to escape `{` and `}` inside a character class. You also don't need to escape `]` is it's the very first character. See [my `replaceAll()` comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41669207/how-to-split-a-string-with-two-reserved-characters#comment70536515_41669207).

Comment: I suppose your example is an overly-simplified situation, because if your strings always begin with `[{` and end with `}]`, and if it's the only occurrences of brackets and curly braces, then just remove the two first and the two last characters...

Comment: @Andreas, how would you distinguish between a literal `[` and a `[` that introduces several different options (such as [abc] which matches a or b or c).

Comment: @Andreas, notice that my first `[` is not escaped, because it is not meant to match a literal `[` but to introduce options.

Comment: @DavidChoweller In the regex `"[]{}\\[]"`, the first `[` and the last `]` define the character class. The `]`, `{`, and `}` are not escaped, but the `\\[` is an escaped `[`. So that Java string defines a regex with a single character class of four characters: `]`, `{`, `}`, and `[` (in that order, though order is unimportant).

Comment: @Andreas, I get your point now, but I find that usage unclear and hard to read.

Comment: @DavidChoweller Then go ahead and escape `]`, but most special characters don't need escaping in a character class, e.g. `{`, `}`, `.`, `*`, `+`, `?`, ...

Comment: Good to know in general, @Andreas.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this.

```
String []str=items.replace("[{","").replace("}]","").split(",");
        Log.e("first",str[0]);
        Log.e("second",str[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
items = items.replace("\\[\\{", "").replace("\\}\\]", "");
```